# SQL - find rows having n duplicate values

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
    OrderId |  CustomerId  |  ProductName
    ======================================
      73    |  301         |  Sponge
      74    |  508         |  Garbage Bag
      75    |  301         |  Spoon
      76    |  301         |  Bacon
      77    |  508         |  Dog treats
      78    |  301         |  Paper
      79    |  905         |  Text book
```

and I want to find a customer who has made two orders in the past.  How would I set up the query?

For the table above, the query would return the two rows for customer 508.

How would I modify it to return customers who have one previous order, so that it would return the row for customer 905?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select customerId, count(*) 
from mytable
group by customerId
having count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only `CustomerId` of those who have exactly one order in table (they exist once) then the following query groups customers and counts how many times they appear in a table (here showing only those who appear once, modify as you wish).

```
SELECT
  CustomerId
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Let's say you want to list every customer and number of orders they've placed but no less than 2 then modify above query to add `COUNT(*)` in column list to be selected and the `HAVING` condition like that:

```
SELECT
  CustomerId
  COUNT(*) AS no_of_orders
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a SQL query of something like that just yesterday.

I adapted it to your table, but I'm not 100% sure it will work.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE COMMANDS
SELECT OrderId, ProductName, COUNT(CustomerId) AS NbCmds
FROM your_table
GROUP BY OrderId;

SELECT CustomerId
FROM COMMANDS
WHERE NbCmds > 1;
```

Edit : You can also do it with a `HAVING` clause. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)